# How can I alias or rewrite a set of resource routes to another namespace in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a bunch of resources that I want to make available at both `/api/[PATH]` and `/api/v1/[PATH]`. In other words, both `/api/tasks/12` and `/api/v1/tasks/12` should be routed to `Api::V1::TasksController#show`. However, for reasons of backward-compatibility I *don't* want to use external redirects - all the routing should happen internally.

This is the best I've found so far, but it requires replicating the `resource` declarations:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1, as: 'v1' do
      resource :profile, only: [:show]
      resources :notifications, only: [:create]
      resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update]
    end

    scope module: 'v1' do
      resource :profile, only: [:show]
      resources :notifications, only: [:create]
      resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update]
    end
  end
```

Yes, I could put them in a Proc if I really wanted to avoid duplication, but that just seems ridiculous.
I tried something like `match '*path', path: '/v1', via: :all` (inside the first `namespace`) but that didn't seem to work.

Surely there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

**Routes**

I understand your question - you want the same routes (including controllers) to be defined for the `/v1` API as the standard `/api`.

The best I can give is to help you define some [routing concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns):

```
#config/routes.rb
concern :api do
  resource :profile, only: [:show]
  resources :notifications, only: [:create]
  resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update]
end

namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  scope module: "v1" do
    concerns :api
  end
  namespace :v1, as: 'v1' do
    concerns: :api
  end
end
```

I know it's a bit WET, but it's the surest way to achieve what you're looking for